# Run content script without loading active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I run the content script without reloading the active tab?

The content script only works when I refresh the active tab.

**Manifest.js**

```
{
  "name": "CMS",
  "description": "A simple CMS solution that can update a website contents and images without modifying the current website structure.",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon48.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.bundle.js"],
      "css": ["content.styles.css"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "content.styles.css",
    "icon128.png",
    "icon48.png"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**content_script**

```
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for (const elt of paragraphs) {
  elt.style['border'] = '1px solid green';
}
```

Comment: There's no need to run it because you can do the same in content.styles.css: `* { border: 1px solid green !important }` If you still need it for whatever reason then use MutationObserver.

Comment: im using thr `* { border: 1px solid green !important }` to detect html markups. since I suppose to create CMS that edits texts